# How do I quiet image_submit_tag from params hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anyone know how to eliminate the x and y params when you use image_submit_tag with a get method?

I have a simple search form, and using get to pass the value in the url. When I use image_submit_tag, it also appends the x and y coords, so I get urls like

```
http://example.com?q=somesearchterm&x=15&y=12
```

When I have used submit_tag, I can use the :name => nil attribute (was in one of Ryan Bates' Railscasts), but it doesn't seem to work for image_submit_tag. Granted it doesn't affect functionality, but I don't need them and would like them quieted.

Comment: Yeah I had the same problem but didn't know it came from the imageSubmit tag.

Answer (score 2):

That's actually part of HTML and the browser, not Rails. There is not much you can do apart from change your use of the image_submit or intercept the form submission with JS and edit the parameters. You may also be able to use a regular submit and style it using CSS to display an image, or use an image and attach JS to it to submit the form.

Comment: For me, these values are actually getting merged into my parameter list in an unexpected way:

  image_submit_tag('image file.png', :name => 'filter')

This code generates this HTML:

  <input name="filter" src="/images/add_filter.png?1391926927" type="image">

Then the controller gets this:
{"filter.y"=>"9", "filter.x"=>"9", "controller"=>"reports", "action"=>"index"}

I use the name to determine what button was pressed. How are the x and y values getting merged into my name?